# C# get String array out of Microsoft Data Base

Tags: c#, treeview

I'm trying to generate A TreeView in my WinForm Programm.
I have a really big database. I need to get The column names from the wohle database and show then in the TreeView

Is that possible ?

Thank you

Janik

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which "Microsoft Data Base"? If you speak about MS SQL Server you should have a look at `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` This you can load into your code and fill whatever you want...

Comment: You can do this with MySQL too.

Comment: yes MS SQL .... yes but how can I put this column names in a String array or sth else

Comment: Do you know how to connect to a database and load the result of a SELECT into e.g. a DataReader?

Answer (score 1):

If you have problem to draw tree then you can use this (as an example)

```
//Draw TreeView in design or initialize as below
            var treeView = new TreeView
            {
               CheckBoxes = true, // optional, if you need the set true
               Width = 300,       //according you requirement
               Height = 0,
               ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 20, 185, 213),
               Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 9.0f, FontStyle.Bold),
               BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
            };
            Controls.Add(treeView);
            //set location etc.
            var list = _localDb.GetBrowseNodeParents();
            foreach (var node in list)
            {                    
                treeView.Nodes.Add(node.NodeId, node.NodeName).Tag = node.NodeUrl;
                treeView.Nodes[node.NodeId].ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
```

Comment: What is `_localDb` and `GetBrowseNodeParents()`? This answer seems very specific to the question without the question stating anything